# .htaccess rewrite rules issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I am trying to rewrite some urls using mod_rewrite.

I want to rewrite

```
localhost/exotica/pet/somePet/
```

to

```
`localhost/exotica/index.php/types/get/somePet/`
```

I have managed to remove index.php by using

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|uploads|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /exotica/index.php/$1 [L]
```

so now `localhost/exotica/types/get/somePet` works
i have tried adding as first rule

```
RewriteRule ^pet/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ type/get/$1 [N]
```

but it simply doesnt work so please help me i have no idea how to enable it

I managed to solve it by adding a route `$route['pet/(:any)'] = "type/get/$1";`, but I would prefer to do it using .htacess file

Comment: To go from `/exotica/pet/somePet/` (incoming SEO format) to `/exotica/index.php/types/get/somePet/` is nonsense. At best, you still have to rewrite into "dynamic" format like `/exotica/index.php?types=xxxxx&op=get&name=somePet`, and you might as well do that "up front".

Comment: @anubhava no problem aint solved cause i want to do it using mod rewrite and not codeigniter rutes.

Comment: @PhilPerry i really dont get u. are u sugesting i use that third type? second type of url is what codeigniter uses and first type of url is what i want to use and need it to rewrite to second. have really no idea if second is rewritten internally into third by codeigniter

Comment: What is location of above .htaccess file? Is it in `DocumentRoot` OR `DocumentRoot/exotica`?

Comment: What I'm saying is that you _eventually_ have to get to the format `/index.php?var1=value1&var2=value2` etc. for the server and PHP to be able to handle it. Converting one SEO format to another doesn't get you anywhere. I suppose it's possible to convert SEO1 to SEO2 and _then_ convert SEO2 to dynamic (non-SEO) format, but if you're starting from scratch you might as well do it in one step. Usually this is all done in .htaccess -- does codeigniter do it internally?

Comment: Do you have any indication of what happens (or not happens) when you add the new rule? I just tried your rules on a simple .php page and besides the type/types typo the only problem I get is a problem that the resulting PATH_INFO contains multiple somePet, but this can be solved by adding the DPI flag to the ^pet rule.

Comment: @anubhava the htacess is located in documentRoot/exotica folder

Comment: @LarsLindNilsson i have no what happens and no idea how to test it how do you do it, when trying at some regexp online it was working but when i put it in htacess it doesnt

Comment: You can try to enable the RewriteLog. How this is done depends on the version of the Apache server. In 2.2 it's enabled with the RewriteLog directive in your httpd.conf. In later versions it's done with the LogLevel directive. Both requires that you have some kind of access to the httpd.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Try your rules like this in reverse order:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /exotica/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^pet/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ types/get/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|uploads|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```